# Perl: Multiline match + Adding prefix to all matched lines

Tags: regex, perl, sed, multiline, prefix

I'm a Perl beginner. I usually use "sed" for pattern substitution, but as I need to comment out some multiline sections in a huge file, I thought of using Perl as being more powerful in multiline search.

Pattern Sample:

```
word1 {
    do not care1
    do not care2
    ...
} word2
```

Intended Output:

```
#word1 {
#    do not care1
#    do not care2
#    ...
#} word2
```

I found very useful Q&As on perl multiline matching, but I couldn't find any good/compact/easy solution to add prefix to ALL the matched lines (not just the first line).

For now, this is the code I wrote:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(word1\s*{[^}]*\s*}\s*word2\s.*)/#$1/gm'
```

But unfortunately it can't add the prefix (#) to all the matched lines as below:

```
#word1 {
    do not care1
    do not care2
    ...
} word2
```

Can you help please? I hope the code would still be in 1 line :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the range operator:

```
perl -pe 's/^/#/ if /word1\s*\{/ .. /\}\s*word2/'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @choroba ... I didn't know about the range operator! very intersting.

Comment: I just have a problem once applied that code, I got the prefix added all over the file starting from a bad pattern matching with no word2 i.e. the pattern matching dismissed the condition of {} and continued searching till end of file as if one pattern. Hopefully you got my point.

Comment: @Monster: You could provide better sample data, then.

Comment: Yes, it's just difficult to get all possible conditions without complicating the question. I already accepted your solution, but I hope if you have a solution to exclude getting bad patterns with word2=word3. Thanks again!

Comment: Re-ask with better examples if that's what you want. It's doable, but we'd need some better examples of edge cases to give a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/word1/,/word2/s/^/#/' file
```

Comment: Thanks @potong! I used to use "sed", but once it's multiline, the conditions between word1 and word2 is essential as there are hundreds of instances of word1 and word2 and I don't want to pattern match word1 from one section to word2 of another section. Plus the pattern itself can extend to multiline